# How do I get my mousehook to callback from a seperate thread? C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, hook

How do I get my mousehook to callback from a seperate thread, to avoid it from interfering with my mainthread, and causing mouselag?

```
HHOOK Mousehook;
int trial=0;  //paintflag for testing

LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (wParam)
{
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    trial = 1; //set paintflag
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    break;
case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    break;
}
return CallNextHookEx(Mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

this is the function I have, and it is called with

```
Mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
```

But I have no idea how to make all that into a seperate thread and single call.

Anyone know a good way? Any help would be much appreciated, is it even possible like this?

Comment: Create a worker thread that calls `SetWindowsHookEx` and then goes into a message loop (`GetMessage` + `DispatchMessate` until you want to shut down the thread).

Comment: Thanks you put me on the right track :D If you want to have the honor of posting the answer, you can do so, or just copy paste the answer i posted, so you get the cred i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Atleast for now, this is how I made a designated thread for my mousehook, so that it can run in the background:

declaring my hook and the callback routine

```
HHOOK Mousehook;

LRESULT CALLBACK HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (wParam)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: //incase lmb down
       //
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: //incase of rmb down
      //
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

return CallNextHookEx(Mousehook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is old news however, so whats the trick? First off add threading

```
#include <thread>

using std::thread  //for convenience
```

then we make the function that the thread runs:

```
void mhook()
{ 
MSG msg;
Mousehook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

this will keep the thread waiting for msg'es. Now all we need to do is create the thread like so:

```
thread listen(mhook);
```

this will make a thread that hooks and listens for mouseactions, without disturbing your main thread.